# jQuery simple slider next & prev suffling issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to figure out why my slider is acting strange, it works as desired if you just keep clinking until its reach to end of slider, but if you try to go back in middle it will shuffle some pics.

Here is the website [temp link](http://planit-india.co.in/temp-conference/cto/v2/#!/gallery_beachwear) for demo

I need to hide 3 `<li>` on every **next** button click, and show back them when we click **back** button.

Here is the code i have developed so far.

**HTML**

```
<li id="gallery_beachwear">
<div class="imageSlider">
  <ul class="arrow_nav">
    <li><a href="#next" title="Next" class="arrow-active go-next"> &gt; </a></li>
    <li><a href="#prev" title="Prev" class="arrow-disables go-prev"> &lt; </a></li>
    <li><a href="#!/" title="Close" class="closeBtn"> X </a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="imgList">
    <li>
        <a href="images/gallery/clothing/a.jpg" rel="Appendix"><span class="zoomImg" style="opacity: 0;"></span>
          <img alt="" src="images/gallery/clothing/a.jpg">
        </a>
    </li>
            <li>
        <a href="images/gallery/clothing/b.jpg" rel="Appendix"><span class="zoomImg" style="opacity: 0;"></span>
          <img alt="" src="images/gallery/clothing/b.jpg">
        </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div> <!-- End of slider -->
</li>
```

I have created a function to re use since i have 2 slider

**JS**

```
function imageGallery(ID) {
    var imgList = $(ID),
    items = imgList.find(".imgList li"),
    arrows = imgList.find("ul.arrow_nav"),
    currenItem = 0,
    itemCount = items.length,
    steps = 3;

    arrows.find('a.go-next').bind('click', (function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var i = currenItem;
            if(i !== 0) {
                i++;
            }

            if( (itemCount - currenItem ) > 4 ) {
                $(items[i]).hide(200);
                i++;
                $(items[i]).hide(200);
                i++;
                $(items[i]).hide(200);
                currenItem = i; 
            }
            console.log(i);
    }));

    arrows.find('a.go-prev').bind('click', (function(e){
        e.preventDefault();

        var i = currenItem;
            if(i !== 0) {
                i--;
            }

            if( (itemCount - currenItem ) > 0 ) {
                //Hide next
                $(items[i]).show(200);
                i--;
                $(items[i]).show(200);
                i--;
                $(items[i]).show(200);
                currenItem = i; 
            }

            console.log(i);
    }));
}

//Calling function
imageGallery("#gallery_beachwear");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is wrong you should change it to

```
arrows.find('a.go-next').bind('click', (function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var i = currenItem;
    if( (itemCount - currenItem ) > 3 ) {
        $(items[i]).hide(200);
        i++;
        $(items[i]).hide(200);
        i++;
        $(items[i]).hide(200);
        i++;
        currenItem = i; 
    }
}));
arrows.find('a.go-prev').bind('click', (function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var i = currenItem;
    if( (currenItem ) > 0 ) {
        //Hide next
        i--;
        $(items[i]).show(200);
        i--;
        $(items[i]).show(200);
        i--;
        $(items[i]).show(200);
        currenItem = i; 
    }
    console.log(i);
}));
```

Comment: thank you so much, when it come to logic I always freaked out. Its working :)